# Binary Search on Large Disk File in C - Problems

Tags: c, linux, binary-search

This question recurs frequently on StackOverflow, but I have read all the previous relevant answers, and have a slight twist on the question.

I have a 23Gb file containing 475 million lines of equal size, with each line consisting of a 40-character hash code followed by an identifier (an integer).

I have a stream of incoming hash codes - billions of them in total - and for each incoming hash code I need to locate it and print out corresponding identifier. This job, while large, only needs to be done once.

The file is too large for me to read into memory and so I have been trying to usemmap in the following way:

```
codes = (char *) mmap(0,statbuf.st_size,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,codefile,0);
```

Then I just do a binary search using address arithmetic based on the address in codes.

This seems to *start working* beautifully and produces a few million identifiers in a few seconds, using 100% of the cpu, but then after some, seemingly random, amount of time it slows down to a crawl. When I look at the process using ps, it has changed from status "R" using 100% of the cpu, to status "D" (diskbound) using 1% of the cpu.

This is not repeatable - I can start the process off again on the same data, and it might run for 5 seconds or 10 seconds before the "slow to crawl" happens. Once last night, I got nearly a minute out of it before this happened.

Everything is read only, I am not attempting any writes to the file, and I have stopped all other processes (that I control) on the machine. It is a modern Red Hat Enterprise Linux 64-bit machine.

Does anyone know why the process becomes disk-bound and how to stop it?

UPDATE:

Thanks to everyone for answering, and for your ideas; I had not previously tried all the various improvements before because I was wondering if I was somehow using mmap incorrectly. But the gist of the answers seemed to be that unless I could squeeze everything into memory, I would inevitable run into problems. So I squashed the size of the hash code to the size of the leading prefix that did not create any duplicates - the first 15 characters were enough. Then I pulled the resulting file into memory, and ran the incoming hash codes in batches of about 2 billion each.

Comment: You're hitting the limitations of virtual memory.  While the active data set fits in memory, everything is hunkydory; when you need to do random access over a data set too large to fit in memory, you start paging hard, becoming disk bound.  There isn't an easy way around that.  Is the integer stored as a 4-byte or 8-byte binary value, or as a character string?  Is restructuring the 23 GiB file a possibility?

Comment: @paxdiablo: The problem isn't the limits of the size of virtual memory; the problem is the underlying physical memory.  The program is still running, but random access over 23 GiB of data when physical memory is, say, 16 GiB, means that once you've got 2/3 of the file in memory, thereafter, on average, you're having to read a new page for one memory access in three, which is painfully slow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, I realised what you meant after a re-read (hence my deleted comment). What threw me was the assertion that it was a limitation of virtual memory (I read that as size) rather than virtual memory _management_ (ie, mapping, as you've explained in your response).

Comment: How much memory do you have?  Specifically, how many of the _incoming_ hash codes could you hold in memory at once (and sort)?  Could you invert the problem, reading the file sequentially and matching it against the incoming data, instead of vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is split the file.

Make one file with the hash-codes and another with the integer ids. Since the rows are the same then it will line up fine after the result is found. Also you can try an approach that puts every nth hash into another file and then stores the index.

For example, every 1000th hash key put into a new file with the index and then load that into memory. Then binary scan that instead. This will tell you the range of 1000 entries that need to be further scanned in the file. Yes that will do it fine! But probably much less than that. Like probably every 20th record or so will divide that file size down by 20 +- if I am thinking good.

In other words after scanning you only need to touch a few kilobytes of the file on disk.

Another option is to split the file and put it in memory on multiple machines. Then just binary scan each file. This will yield the absolute fastest possible search with zero disk access...

Comment: Splitting the 40-byte hash codes and 4-or-8-byte integers may not achieve much, you're talking about a 9-or-17% reduction. Your second suggestion seems more promising.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it contained two good ideas, even if it didn't cover all the aspects of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered hacking a PATRICIA trie algorithm up? It seems to me that if you can build a PATRICIA tree representation of your data file, which refers to the file for the hash and integer values, then you might be able to reduce each item to node pointers (2*64 bits?), bit test offsets (1 byte in this scenario) and file offsets (uint64_t, which might need to correspond to multiple fseek()s).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why the process becomes disk-bound and how to stop it?

Binary search requires a lot of seeking within the file. In the case where the whole file doesn't fit in memory, the page cache doesn't handle the big seeks very well, resulting in the behaviour you're seeing.

The best way to deal with this is to reduce/prevent the big seeks and make the page cache work for you.

Three ideas for you:

**If you can sort the input stream**, you can search the file in chunks, using something like the following algorithm:

```
code_block <- mmap the first N entries of the file, where N entries fit in memory
max_code <- code_block[N - 1]
while(input codes remain) {
  input_code <- next input code
  while(input_code > max_code)  {
    code_block <- mmap the next N entries of the file
    max_code <- code_block[N - 1]
  }
  binary search for input code in code_block
}
```

---

**If you can't sort the input stream**, you could reduce your disk seeks by building an in-memory index of the data. Pass over the large file, and make a `table` that is:

```
record_hash, offset into file where this record starts
```

Don't store all records in this table - store only every Kth record. Pick a large K, but small enough that this fits in memory.

To search the large file for a given target hash, do a binary search in the in-memory table to find the biggest hash in the `table` that is smaller than the target hash. Say this is `table[h]`. Then, mmap the segment starting at `table[h].offset` and ending at `table[h+1].offset`, and do a final binary search. This will dramatically reduce the number of disk seeks.

If this isn't enough, you can have multiple layers of indexes:

```
 record_hash, offset into index where the next index starts
```

Of course, you'll need to know ahead of time how many layers of index there are.

---

Lastly, **if you have extra money available** you can always buy more than 23 gb of RAM, and make this a memory bound problem again (I just looked at Dell's website - you pick up a new low-end workstation with 32 GB of RAM for just under $1,400 Australian dollars). Of course, it will take a while to read that much data in from disk, but once it's there, you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mmap`, consider just using plain old `lseek`+`read`. You can define some helper functions to read a hash value or its corresponding integer:

```
void read_hash(int line, char *hashbuf) {
    lseek64(fd, ((uint64_t)line) * line_len, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, hashbuf, 40);
}

int read_int(int line) {
    lseek64(fd, ((uint64_t)line) * line_len + 40, SEEK_SET);
    int ret;
    read(fd, &ret, sizeof(int));
    return ret;
}
```

then just do your binary search as usual. It might be a bit slower, but it won't start chewing up your virtual memory.

Comment: +1.  This will still populate the page cache, which is technically part of the kernel's VM subsystem. But, in my experience, the VM subsystem deals better with stress on unmapped pages than mmap'd pages. This approach might not help, but it is an easy thing to try.

Comment: This is good, but combining it with a partial ordered map in memory is better. In other words instead of doing 24 or 16 disk reads to locate the record, use a partial search. In other words every 64th record for example, and that narrows it down extremely. Then use this disk access technique on the much smaller range.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think that reducing the total amount of I/O is critical, and the partial maps are a good way to do that.

Comment: Ha, I moved FROM lseek to mmap because that got disk bound as well.

Comment: why you think `lseek` will be faster than `mmap`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the back story. So it is hard to give you definitive advice. How much memory do you have? How sophisticated is your hard drive? Is this a learning project? Who's paying for your time? 32GB of ram doesn't seem so expensive compared to two days of work of person that makes $50/h. How fast does this need to run? How far outside the box are you willing to go? Does your solution need to use advanced OS concepts? Are you married to a program in C? How about making Postgres handle this?

Here's is a low risk alternative. This option isn't as intellectually appealing as the other suggestions but has the potential to give you significant gains. Separate the file into 3 chunks of 8GB or 6 chunks of 4GB (depending on the machines you have around, it needs to comfortably fit in memory). On each machine run the same software, but in memory and put an RPC stub around each. Write an RPC caller to each of your 3 or 6 workers to determine the integer associated with a given hash code.

Comment: All good points... as it turns out, the machine has 32Gb RAM already (which begs the question of why it got diskbound in the first place). I need the data for a research project of mine, but it's a once-off run to create a data set that I will subsequently store in a database, so it's not specifically a learning project in programming, though I need to learn enough to do it and may do similar things in the future. Language is C because that's what I know best..